Simulating a linear mixed model with a cross-level interaction explaining variance in random slopes
I am trying to simulate a dataset in R using a linear mixed model designed to exhibit a cross-level interaction that explains variance in random slopes. However, the code below results in a significant proportion of explained variance in random intercepts but not in random slopes. I also attempted to define u1, which represents the variance in slopes as a function of the level-2 predictor mean_iq, but without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
library(lme4)

set.seed(8437)
# Set parameters
n_studies <- 100
n_per_group <- 50
n_total <- n_studies * n_per_group

# Generate level-1 predictors
study_id <- rep(1:n_studies, each = n_per_group)
treatment <- factor(sample(c("CG", "EG"), n_total, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5)))
iq <- rnorm(n_total, 100, 10) # Continuous level-1 predictor
mean_iq <- ave(iq, study_id)# Level-2 predictor

# Specify fixed effects
b0 <- 0.5 # Intercept (reference level: CG)
b1 <- 1.7 # Effect of treatment (EG vs CG)
b2 <- 0.2 # Effect of iq (level-1)
b3 <- 2.5 # Effect of level-2 predictor (mean IQ per group)
b4 <- 0.3 # Interaction effect (treatment in EG * mean_iq)

# Generate random effects
u0 <- rnorm(n_studies, .1, 0.5)[study_id] # Random intercepts
u1 <- rnorm(n_studies, .3, 0.3)[study_id] # Random slopes for iq

# Calculate outcome with interaction
y <- b0 + 
  b1 * (treatment == "EG") + 
  b2 * iq + 
  b3 * mean_iq +
  b4 * (treatment == "EG") * mean_iq + 
  u0 + u1 * iq + 
  rnorm(n_total, 0, 1)

# Combine into dataset
data <- data.frame(y, treatment, iq, study_id)

# Fit the full model
model_full <- lmer(y ~ iq + treatment * mean_iq + (1 + iq | study_id), data = data)
summary(model_full)

model_reduced <- lmer(y ~ iq + treatment + mean_iq + (1 + iq | study_id), data = data)
summary(model_reduced)

# Compare models
anova(model_reduced, model_full)


The simulation seems well structured, but I think there are a few pragmatic issues that are causing the issues you note in your post.
First, the level-1 error terms are probably too small for this simulation.  (You will note that when you run the code, it generates a singularity complaint at the boundary.  This is causing a convergence issue...the other clue for this is the estimated correlation between u0 and u1 as 1.0.)  If you bump this from 1 to 2, this issue appears to resolve.
Second, for a simulation of this nature, I'd recommend mean-centering the individual IQs by group, and then report the mean of the IQ by group.  Otherwise, you end up with a strange interpretation issue (and potentially a scaling issue...which I think also was part of the problem).  Thus, if you add the line
 iq <- iq - mean_iq

after the introduction of mean_iq in your syntax, this will mean-center the level-1 variable.
Third, (this is an individual preference, but it does help for simulation result checking after the fact)...include the mean of your level-2 random elements in the estimates (e.g., bump b0 from 0.5 to 0.6 and change the mean for u0 from 0.1 to 0).
When I make these changes, the results appear to run as expected (but for the intercept estimate, and this is always an issue that I've encountered...but all the other effects and parameters appear to be reproduced reasonably well).
Finally, for a simulation such as this, I would model the correlation between the intercept and slope errors.  (Graphically, if you imagine predicting some score from an IQ measure...which is centered at 100...the vertical intercept exists rather far away from here...and if you change the slope, it will indeed change the vertical intercept...and in this case, even with mean-centering the level-1 iq, you still have the mean_iq term in the model.)  I didn't try running this here, but my guess is that if you had incorporated this into the simulation, then the small error standard deviation may have actually worked.
Happy to clarify more as needed.

That was already very helpful. Thank you! I incorporated these changes, but the strange thing is that the full model does not explain variance in random slopes, only in random intercepts.
I also experimented with larger values for b4, but without success. Additionally, I explicitly tried modeling the covariance between random intercepts and slopes using the mvrnormfunction
This, however, led to non-convergence and a correlation between intercept and slope of -1, indicating something is not quite right with the setup.

I'm not sure what you mean by "not explain variance in random slopes"...I get an estimate for the slope variance, and it nearly matches the value you set for u1. Perhaps you may wish to run the model w/ and w/o the random slope to see if there is a difference.

Sorry, that was unclear. What I actually meant is that if the interaction treatment * mean_iq explained part of the random slope variance, I would expect the residual variance of iq to decrease in the full model. However, it remains 0.09621 in the full model and 0.09631 in the reduced model, showing hardly any difference. The random intercept variances, on the other hand, do differ: 0.13066 in the reduced model vs 0.12149 in the full model. But maybe I am missing something essential here.
